# Unable to get desired hash for CSV format in perl

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

I have exported most common emp table as CSV. I would like to take each column name as hash key and store the values in an array.

Below is the code

```
 use Data::Dumper;
    open($fh,"<EMP.csv");
    %hash = ();

    local $/= "\n";

    while(<$fh>){

         @columnNames = split(/,/,$_) if $. ==1;     
         @columnValues = split(/,/,$_);  
          push @{hash->{@columnNames}} ,@columnValues;       
    }

    print Dumper(\%hash);
```

when I try to print the hash I am getting this

```
$VAR1 = {
          '8' => [
                   '"EMPNO"',
                   '"ENAME"',
                   '"JOB"',
                   '"MGR"',
                   '"HIREDATE"',
                   '"SAL"',
                   '"COMM"',
                   '"DEPTNO"
',
                   '"7839"',
                   '"KING"',
                   '"PRESIDENT"',
                   '""',
                   '"11/17/1981"',
                   '"5000"',
                   '""',
                   '"10"
',
```

But I'm expecting this instead

```
$VAR1 = { '"EMPNO"'=>[12,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
          '"EMPNAME"'=>["pavan","kumar"...],

};
```

Comment: I've not seen that syntax for assigning multiple values to a hash in one line before (push @{hash...). Did you find it online somewhere?

Comment: @hash{@array1} = @array2; i am expecting like this...

Comment: That looks a bit Python-y and won't work in Perl. Text::CSV is probably the safest way to go

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to use a slice in a push statement, and that will not work. The array will be in scalar context, which is why you see the key `8`. You would need to loop over the keys to push values onto the arrays. However, why do it that way?

You can use the [`Text::CSV`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::CSV) module for this, which is rather simple and probably more appropriate, assuming you have a real csv format.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({
        binary  => 1,
        eol     => $/,
    });
my %data;
open my $fh, "<", "yourfile.csv" or die $!;
$csv->column_names ($csv->getline($fh));          # get header names

while (my $row = $csv->getline_hr($fh)) {         # get hashref with values
    for my $key (keys %$row) {
        push @{$data{$key}}, $row->{$key};        # store values
    }
}
print Dumper \%data;
```

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite this line

```
push @{hash->{@columnNames}} ,@columnValues;
```

to:

```
foreach my $columnName (@columnNames) {
    my $columnValue = shift @columnValues;
    push @{ $hash{$columnName} }, $columnValue;
}
```

Comment: @hash{@array1) = @array2; how may i get these kind of result for the above one...

Comment: @pavan You cannot use assignment `=` for adding continuous values (because they will be overwritten), and you cannot use slices without the assignment operator. So, you cannot use that method here.

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem:

```
push @{hash->{@columnNames}} ,@columnValues;
```

You're trying to use `@columnNames` as a key in your hash. Perl automatically takes this in a scalar context, thus, giving you a *key* of `8` since there are eight values in the array.

What you want to do is treat the first row in your CSV (which contains the column names) as special since these will be keys to your array.

```
my @column_names = read_csv_row; #Column names
my %employee_hash;
for my $column ( @column_names ) {
    $employee_hash{$column} = [];
}
```

This will give you a hash, keyed by column name to references to arrays. You now have to read in each line of your CSV table, and push each field into its correct column hash;

```
while ( my @employee_fields = read_csv_row ) {   #Your employee record is in @employee
    for my $field_num ( 0..$#employee_fields) {
        push @{ $employee_hash{$column_names[$field_num] }, $employee_fields[$field_num];
    }
}
```

What this is doing is taking each field from the CSV row and pushing it into its correct array reference in the `%employee_hash`. I'm taking advantage that `@column_names` is in the same order as each row. Thus, `$column_names[$field_number]` is the correct hash key, and that should correspond to the `$employee_fields[$field_num]`.

However, the structure you said in your post is probably not what you really want. What you want is something like this:

```
%VAR = {
           7839 =>   {
                        ENAME    => "KING",
                        JOB      => "PRESIDENT",
                        MGR      => "",
                        HIREDATE => "11/17/1981",
                        SAL      => "5000",
                        COMM     => "",
                        DEPTNO   => "10",
                     }
      }
```

This wil key each employee by their employee number, and all of the related employee fields will be part of that value. Then you can talk about Employee number 7839's job title as being `$employee{7839}->{JOB}` and that employee's name being `$employee{7839}->{NAME}`. This way, all of the information about each employee is together in a single record:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
use feature qw(say);

my @column_names = read_csv_row(); #Column name
my %employee_hash;
while ( my @minion_fields = read_csv_row() ) {   #Your employee record is in @employee
    my %minion_hash;
    my $minion_number = $minion_fields[0];
    for my $field_num ( 1..$#minion_fields) {
        $minion_hash{ $column_names[$field_num] } = $minion_fields[$field_num];
    }
    $employee_hash{$minion_number} = \%minion_hash;
}

sub read_csv_row {
    my $row = <DATA> or return;
    chomp $row;
    return split /,\s+/, $row;
}

say Dumper \%employee_hash;
__DATA__
empno, name, job, mgr, hiredate, sal, comm, deptno
7839, king, president, , 11/17/1981, 5000, , 10
1234, prince, vice-president, , 10/1/1980, 3000, , 10
```

<strike>By the way, I haven't tested this code yet. (I'll do that now, and make needed corrections).</strike> You may want to play around with `Text::CSV` which will be a better way of reading in CSV files, and may even help you create these structures (I haven't used it in a long, long time, so I don't remember everything it does). However, I believe that you'll find making your employee structure a hash of hashes with the initial hash keyed by employee number, and the sub-hashes keyed by fields a lot better than a hash of arrays.

Comment: It is quite redundant to assign an empty array ref for the `%employee_hash`, Perl's autovivification will take care of that, and it is somewhat misleading to pretend that it is necessary.

Comment: @TLP Yes, I know, but it does document that I expect the contents of that hash to be an array reference. That bit of *documentation* may help the person who has to support my code.

Comment: If its documentation you want, why not add a comment? `# This hash will contain array refs`.